How to make webpack to use microsoft/signalr from nodejs?
Im doing a poc application using microsoft/signalR in nodeJs (webpack) application. In first approach, signalr library was loaded on page with <script> atributte in <head> section and it worked. Now Im doing second approach: module @microsoft/signalr was installed in node_module directory. But the problem that code looks like this:
 import { HubConnectionBuidler, HttpTransportType, LogLevel } from '@microsoft/signalr' `
 const connection = new HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl('xxxx',{ transport = HttpTransportType.LongPolling}.build(); ...
When code started in browser, the error is displayed:
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js)
SyntaxError: .../node_modules/@microsoft/signalr/dist/esm/FetchHttpClient.js: Unexpected token
And the error code is displayed:
headers: {
  X-Requested-With: 'XMLHttpRequest',
  ...request.headers,
  ^
},

webpack version: 4.47
webpack loaders:
module: {
  rules: [
     {
       test: /\.js$/,
       use: [{
         loader: 'babel-loader'
         options: {
            preset: ['env'],
            plugins: [require('bable-plugin-syntax-dynamix-import')]
         }
    }]
  }]


Which version of Webpack is this? What loaders have you configured?

@AKX post updated

Pretty sure that's not your actual configuration, because it has multiple typos and bad syntax.

you are right, it's code in my  work. I fixed a lot of typos.

The error is caused by your babel-loader (likely an old version) not recognizing the ... spread syntax. You should update your Babel (and Webpack too – 4.47 is from 2023).
However, as discussed in babel-loader's readme, you should not run babel-loader on the contents of node_modules. See the usage example, comment added by me:
module: {
  rules: [
    {
      test: /\.(?:js|mjs|cjs)$/,
      exclude: /node_modules/,  // <- add this!
      use: {
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        ...

